# редактирование item в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

У меня есть `activity_edit` на котором, пользователь нажимая на кнопку "добавить", наполняет `ArrayList`. Впоследствии, из элементов этого `ArrayList` я создаю `RecyclerView`.
Сейчас я хочу добавить возможность редактирования `item`ов данного `RecyclerView`. Сижу, ломаю голову как лучше это сделать. Вижу 2 варианта:

1. Из `RecyclerView` с помощью `Parcelable` я возвращаю на `activity_edit` элемент, который нужно редактировать. Сетю переданные значение в соответствующие `View`. И перегружаю уже созданный метод обработки нажатия кнопки "добавить", т.к. в данном случае нужно в `ArrayList` изменить элемент, а не добавить новый.Т.е. в `activity_edit` будут как методы относящиеся к добавлению элементов к `ArrayList`, так и методы редактирования этих элементов.
2. Создаю `activity_edit_2`, аналогичное `activity_edit`, но нажатие кнопки добавить, описывается отдельным методом, без перегрузки. В этом случае в каждом `activity` будут свои специфичные методы.
   Как лучше сделать?

Comment: Тоесть у вас на одной активности отображается список, а на другой можно редактировать? Или как?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: Опишите подробнее где у вас объявлен `ArrayList`, и где вы "создаете" `RecyclerView`. Обычно между фрагментами и активити передают не все данные, а идентификаторы. В вашем случае достаточно передавать позицию в списке (-1 - для нового элемента, 0..size()-1 - для редактирования), сам список должен быть доступен либо из shared viewmodel'и, либо через бд (но тогда идентификация не по позиции, а по id).

Answer (score 1):

Есть третий метод, и ничего ненужно перегружать. есть фрагментА и фрагментВ. при вызове фрагА создаете бандл и кладете в него аргумент (любой, стринг, инт, какой угодно) и присваиваете ему значение. Если фрагмент был вызван методом "добавить итем", кладете например целое число 1, а если методом "редактировать" - 2. А уже в вызываемом фрагменте в метод кнопки сохранить вставляете свитч, который в зависимости от того, какой пришел аргумент, выполняет тот или иной код.

Код вызывающего фрагмента.

```
   //вызываем фрагмент для добавления итема

    public void method1() {
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("ARG", 1); // кладем в бандл аргумент с ключом ARG значеним 1
                    navController.navigate(R.id.some_destination, bundle); // переходим в вызываемый фрагмент, передаем ему бандл
                    getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener("ADD_KEY", this, this::onFragmentResult); // устанавливаем листенер полученного результата по ключу ADD_KEY
    }
    
    // вызываем фрагмент для редактирования итема

    public void method2() {
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
                    bundle.putInt("ARG", 2); // кладем в бандл аргумент с ключом ARG значеним 2
                    navController.navigate(R.id.some_destination, bundle);
                    getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener("EDIT_KEY", this, this::onFragmentResult);
    }
    
    // обрабатываем полученный результат

    @Override
    public void onFragmentResult(@NonNull String requestKey, @NonNull Bundle result) {
        switch (requestKey) { //получаем результат по ключу
            case "ADD_KEY": если мы вызывали фрагмент для добавления
                String string = result.getString("add_string") // получаем данные по ключи add_string
                break;
            case "EDIT_KEY": //если мы вызывали фрагмент для редактирования
                String string = result.getString("edit_string") // получаем данные по ключи edit_string
                break;
        }
    }
```

код вызываемого фрагмента

```
public void someMethod(){
            
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            int request_key = getArguments().getInt("ARG"); // здесь получаем аргумент по ключу ARG
            switch (request_key) { // обрабатываем аргумент 
                case 1: // если аргумент ARG имеет значение 1
                    bundle.putString("add_string", "some_text"); // записываем данные в бандл по ключу add_string
                    getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResult("ADD_KEY", bundle); // запаковываем данные в результат с ключом ADD_KEY
                    break;
                case 2: // если аргумент ARG имеет значение 2
                    bundle.putString("edit_string", "some_text"); // записываем данные в бандл по ключу edit_string
                    getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResult("EDIT_KEY", bundle); // запаковываем данные в результат с ключом EDIT_KEY
                    break;
            }
            navController.popBackStack(); // возвращаемся в исходный фрагмент
 
    }
```

Решил добавить подобие схемы, по коду можно запутаться. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]